# Unable to mount partition from NAS RAID array to recover data

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, raid, mdadm

I have one disk of a 2 disk raid1 array that failed in the raid device. The manufacturer and subsequent investigation indicates it is formatted as a linux disk.

`fdisk -l` displays

```
Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       41       1953       1913 956.5K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2 ...
...
/dev/sdb9  6504448    8503295    1998848   976M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb10 8503296 7814035254 7805531959   3.6T Microsoft basic data
```

I run

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb10 /media/seagate
```

and get

```
mount: /media/seagate: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
```

Following the advice [here](https://serverfault.com/a/383373) I ran

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md0 /dev/sdb10
```

producing:

```
mdadm: /dev/sdb10 is busy - skipping
```

`mdadm --examine` produces

```
         Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : e733e938:772dc035:5c104e46:4d4fe2da
           Name : BA-001075384F44:8
  Creation Time : Wed Apr 24 18:37:09 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 7805529911 (3721.97 GiB 3996.43 GB)
     Array Size : 3902764819 (3721.97 GiB 3996.43 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7805529638 (3721.97 GiB 3996.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=273 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b8ca69f9:bba3bbc2:33f7033e:67308d4f

    Update Time : Fri Dec 14 13:54:41 2018
       Checksum : a891168f - correct
         Events : 2


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I am at an impasse it seems. Can anyone point me in the right direction for mounting this partition and (hopefully) recovering the data on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [these instructions](https://quonn.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/how-to-mount-lvm-partition-on-ubuntu/) and was able to see the LVM both in terminal window and in GUI interface.

But then:

```
mount /dev/vg8/lv8 /mnt/sd1
```

Generated: 
    “Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg8-lv8,
     missing codepage or helper program, or other error”

Followed [the advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315070) and used

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg8/lv8
```

But got message

```
/dev/vg8/lv8 contains a ext4 file system
  last mounted on /shares/public on Tue Sept 16 20:00:52 1975
Proceed anyway?
```

[JerryFrey](https://superuser.com/a/1388020/471734) suggested using a file recovery such as [foremost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64889/how-to-mount-recover-data-on-a-disk-that-was-part-of-a-mdadm-raid-1-on-another-m). I ended up doing that and recovered all the files albeit without file names or a directory tree.